# Wordpress where are stored pages info

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I can't found in which mysql table are stored "Pages" records for example page name. I know that post records are stored in `wp_posts` table.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

WordPress treating page data as post data for DB.
So, please check your `wp_posts` db have page data also.

Answer (score 3):

In wp_posts with post_type=page
and extra postdata are stored in wp_postmeta like thumbnail is and other custom fields

Answer (score 0):

check your data base table **wp_post** and field **post_content** which have **longtext** type. check the **ping_status** field should be **open**.

**post_content** have the all data of the particular page and post.

Answer (score 0):

The title of a page would be stored in the `wp_posts` table

But if you're looking for the page-template in use by that page you would look in the `wp_postmeta` table for `_wp_page_template` in the `meta_key` column